# How to make a new array based on properties of objects in another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, object

I am trying to create an array of names of students who received 3.5 GPA or higher based on the students array that I am presented with. I am having trouble pushing the names to the new array, I keep printing undefined.

```
const students = [
  { name: "Paisley Parker", gpa: 4.0 },
  { name: "Lake Herr", gpa: 3.2 },
  { name: "Promise Lansing", gpa: 3.9 },
  { name: "Friar Park", gpa: 2.8 },
  { name: "Mason Amitie", gpa: 3.49 }
]

function getDeansList(studentList) {
  let deansList = [];
  for(i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
if(students.gpa >= 3.5) return deansList.push(students.name);
  }
}

console.log(getDeansList(students))
```

I have tried many variations of the for loop and tried to get a for in loop to work. Cant seem to figure out how to target the gpa number specifically for the objects in my students array. I am still learning so any advice is appreciated!

Comment: `const getDeansList = studentList => studentList.filter(s => s.gpa >= 3.5)`. (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: Use danh's solution, it's cleaner. As to why your code wasn't working - in your loop, inside your `if(...)`, you need to use `students[i]`, since you are looping through the list of students, and checking *individual* entries / students / elements of your array.

Comment: thank you both! very helpful and informative, I was way overthinking.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you overthinked about this requirement, You can simply achieve this by using [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method.

Live Demo **:**

```js
const students = [
  { name: "Paisley Parker", gpa: 4.0 },
  { name: "Lake Herr", gpa: 3.2 },
  { name: "Promise Lansing", gpa: 3.9 },
  { name: "Friar Park", gpa: 2.8 },
  { name: "Mason Amitie", gpa: 3.49 }
];

const result = students.filter(({ gpa }) => gpa >= 3.5);

console.log(result);
```